# Draggable/resizable image on image

Tags: jquery, draggable, resizable

i want to make resizable, draggalbe image in front of another image, when I try to make it resizable it brokes all css ant it's not in front of first image.
    [JSFiddler Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dara7x/72b1tLpv/)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".el").click(function() {

        $("#bg").before(function() {
            return $(".el").clone().toggleClass('res').draggable({
              containment: "#bg"
            });
        });

        });
        $("#bg").droppable({
          drop: function( event, ui ) {
             x = ui.helper.clone();

          }
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you're cloning ALL `.el` so you'll get 1 on first click then 2 on the second then 4, 8, 16, etc. Secondly, you're placing the cloned element *before* `#bg` rather than inside it.

Use `.append` in place of `.before` and only clone the instance of `.el` that is within `#elements`. E.G:

```
$("#bg").append(function() {
    return $("#elements .el").clone().addClass('res').draggable({
      containment: "#bg"
    });
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/72b1tLpv/1/

---

**UPDATE:**

For *some reason* I can only `append()` one instance but I will `prepend()` as many as I like. (Switch `$("#bg").append(function(){` for `$("#bg").prepend(function(){` to see for yourself.)

If this is an issue for you you can append it *after* the first image. IE:

`$("#bg img:first").after(function() {`

(http://jsfiddle.net/72b1tLpv/2/)

Comment: Thanks, and how about resizable?